# Java Spring - Accessing Data with MongoDB execution error

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven

I would like to setup a simple example of **Java Spring and MongoDB** but I have not been able yet. In this case, I am following the example in Spring [web](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/).

I have installed Maven, Mongo DB and Java JDK 1.8 with JRE8. Furthermore, in the **pom.xml** file, I have had to include this dependency due to a compilation error:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Finally, following the mentioned web instructions, I type:

**mvn spring-boot:run**
or
java -jar target/gs-accessing-data-mongodb-0.1.0.jar

In the first case, spring-boot, I obtain the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project gs-accessing-data-mongodb: An exception occured while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'messageConverters' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters]: Factory method 'messageConverters' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException -> [Help 1]
```

Any ideas of what to do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not it works and my dependencies look like this:

```
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And the result in console:

```
Customers found with findAll():
-------------------------------
Customer[id=55b52943dac11e2ab8262f16, firstName='Alice', lastName='Smith']
Customer[id=55b52944dac11e2ab8262f17, firstName='Bob', lastName='Smith']

Customer found with findByFirstName('Alice'):
--------------------------------
Customer[id=55b52943dac11e2ab8262f16, firstName='Alice', lastName='Smith']
Customers found with findByLastName('Smith'):
--------------------------------
Customer[id=55b52943dac11e2ab8262f16, firstName='Alice', lastName='Smith']
Customer[id=55b52944dac11e2ab8262f17, firstName='Bob', lastName='Smith']
2015-07-26 20:39:00.438  INFO 1884 --- [lication.main()] hello.Application                        : Started Application in 4.726 seconds (JVM running for 7.57)
```